# encontrar una fila(s) con DataTable.Select

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

Realizo la siguiente instrucción..

```
 DataRow[] results = m_dtableKardex.Select("IdReferencia = "                 + l_intIdReferencia         + " OR IdReferencia IS NULL" +
                                                   " AND IdTamano = "               + l_intIdTamano             + " OR IdTamano IS NULL" +
                                                   " AND IdLamina = "               + l_intIdLamina             + " OR IdLamina IS NULL" +
                                                   " AND IdColorLamina = "          + l_intIdColorLamina        + " OR IdColorLamina IS NULL" +
                                                   " AND IdAcabado = "              + l_intIdAcabadoHerraje     + " OR IdAcabado IS NULL" +
                                                   " AND IdColorRecubrimiento = "   + l_intIdColorRecubrimiento + " OR IdColorRecubrimiento IS NULL" +
                                                   " AND IdColorSuperficial ="      + l_intIdColorSuperficial   + " OR IdColorSuperficial IS NULL");
```

donde alguno de las condiciones pueden ser null, pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> No se controló System.NullReferenceException
>     Message=Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

si solo envío un dato valido para que muestre el resultado del DataRow, con el OR  IS NULL Obviaría los demás variables??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código que compartes presenta un problema: no se está teniendo en cuenta la precedencia de operadores. En casi todos los lenguajes el operador `Y` tiene más precedencia que el operador `O` (porque `Y` es más restrictivo).

Eso quiere decir que aunque en tu código lo tengas ordenado como:

```
  a O b
Y c O d 
Y e O f
```

Esa representación gráfica no se corresponde con la interpretación que se va a hacer de las condiciones. Porque al tener `O` menos precedencia que `Y`, entonces lo que realmente se está haciendo es:

```
  a 
O (b Y c) 
O (d Y e) 
O f
```

La representación gráfica que haces de la condición no coincide con su interpretación que se va a hacer por parte del lenguaje, y eso haría que pueda escaparse una variable con valor NULL que cause el error que recibes.

La solución sería usar paréntesis para separar correctamente las operaciones, porque lo que parece que quieres hacer es:

```
  (a O b) 
Y (c O d) 
Y (e O f)
```

Que aplicado a tu código se vería como esto:

```
 DataRow[] results = m_dtableKardex.Select("(IdReferencia = "           + l_intIdReferencia         + " OR IdReferencia IS NULL)" +
                                      " AND (IdTamano = "               + l_intIdTamano             + " OR IdTamano IS NULL)" +
                                      " AND (IdLamina = "               + l_intIdLamina             + " OR IdLamina IS NULL)" +
                                      " AND (IdColorLamina = "          + l_intIdColorLamina        + " OR IdColorLamina IS NULL) " +
                                      " AND (IdAcabado = "              + l_intIdAcabadoHerraje     + " OR IdAcabado IS NULL) " +
                                      " AND (IdColorRecubrimiento = "   + l_intIdColorRecubrimiento + " OR IdColorRecubrimiento IS NULL)" +
                                      " AND (IdColorSuperficial = "     + l_intIdColorSuperficial   + " OR IdColorSuperficial IS NULL)");
```

Comment: Si alvaro olvide que las condiciones se deben manejar bien, debe ser como si lo hiciera en una consulta sql, Gracias